# why list product duplicates elements after doing append action in python

Tags: python, list

this is really a puzzle issue, while debugging my code, I found this really strange error (it happened in both python 3.6 and 3.7, have not tested on others)

when I am looping through a simple list, take out the element and assigned in to a dict, creating and new list of dict.

the list.append does not just add on the new element, but it also replaces the previous elements.

simple python code:

```
d1 = {}
l1=["A1,1","B2,2"]
l2 =[]
for rows in l1:
    print("----- l2 before append")
    print(l2)
    d1["ID"]=rows
    print("-------dict to append ")
    print(d1)
    l2.append(d1)
    print("----- l2 after append")
    print(l2)
```

print result:

```
----- l2 before append
[]
-------dict to append 
{'ID': 'A1,1'}
----- l2 after append
[{'ID': 'A1,1'}]
----- l2 before append
[{'ID': 'A1,1'}]
-------dict to append 
{'ID': 'B2,2'}
----- l2 after append
[{'ID': 'B2,2'}, {'ID': 'B2,2'}]
```

I expected the output of l2 to be [{'ID': 'A1,1'}, {'ID': 'B2,2'}]
but I get [{'ID': 'B2,2'}, {'ID': 'B2,2'}]

Comment: Nothing puzzling - you re-assigned the key "id" in your dict `d1` during the for loop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: okay, I got it, so I suppose to create a new list to append instead, else it is referring to the old list and all item in the list are reflected that.

Comment: @Justin You don't have a new `d1`. Reassigning the key does not reassign the dictionary. Therefore, with each `append`, you have another reference to the same dictionary. If you want a new dictionary, you need to move the `d1 = {}` line under the loop.

Comment: thank you Luke, you solved this.. really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
l1=["A1,1","B2,2"]
l2 =[]
for rows in l1:
    d1 = {}
    #print(id(d1)) 
    # you will find it's a different object each time.
    d1["ID"]=rows
    l2.append(d1)
print(l2)
```

Or you can do it in this way as below

```
l1=["A1,1","B2,2"]
l2 = [{"ID":i } for i in l1]
print(l2)
```

Output is

```
[{'ID': 'A1,1'}, {'ID': 'B2,2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A dict can only contain unique keys, so `'ID'` is overridden with the new value.

Your list is actually containing the value of the dict`d1` if `d1` changes, your list will change.

You're using a global dict, and the value changes with the second for loop pass, to to get your intended results, put the `d1 = {}` inside your for loop instead.